# Adding Objects to View

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

Im making a game of sorts, where balls are added to the screen.  I need to be able to add custom balls (different speeds/images, ect) at time intervals (i.e. ball type 1 gets added every 15 seconds, whereas ball type 2 gets added every 30 seconds).  I need these balls to be `UIImageView` (at least with the setup I have right now to check collisions).

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Also, How to make the player (a `UIImageView`) the start button.  I have an `IBAction` that starts the game.  I cannot connect the `UIImageView` and the `IBAction` though...

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer first, but really you don't want to use `UIImageView` for user interaction. A `UIButton` can be set to the type 'custom' and then display an image (you can set the image in interface builder or programmatically):

```
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnMyButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is then much easier to pick up `IBAction` etc.

As regards creating the balls dynamically, creating a new `UIImageView` programmatically is easy using the `initWithImage` method, I suggest you read up on the `UIImageView` class reference at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

`UIImageView` inherits from `UIView` so after creating each image, just add it as a sub view using something like:

```
[self.view addSubView:newImageView];
```

Regarding the timer element, `NSTimer` is the place to look for this. I don't have much experience using these but it should be straightforward. Reference can be found at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Hth

Comment: I changed the ball the player controls to a button.  A few problems with that:1) If I press the start button more than once, the app crashes (something wrong with my start IBaction?) 2) I cannot move the button with a user touch.  Ill paste the code, one sec

Comment: -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    player.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
} //code to move the button

Comment: -(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
   
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} ///code to start the game

Comment: tried to make a new start...still nothing...any ideas?-(IBAction)start
{
    if (player.center.x != self.view.center.x || player.center.y != self.view.center.y) 
    {
       randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(moveEnemy) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
    }
}

Comment: I would add a Boolean variable to check whether the game has started (set it to true on first run of the start method) and then test it's value on subsequent runs so you don't run the code twice. Alternatively you could doable user interaction for the button after the start method has been run.